# Need to add "This answer helped" for an FAQ/KB using PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, rank

I've found ways to rank existing values but it's been awhile and I'm not sure the best way to add a "This answered my question" function to my KB/FAQ.  I guess my biggest problem is separating multiple queries into individual ones so I can plug this feature in.  I'm assuming I'd just have to add a insert into the database that will +1 each time someone clicks the button, but it's been awhile and I haven't done this before.

As a further clarification, Im using this within a Facebook app I'm making so need to rate individual answers that are generated by the search of my knowledge base to produce better answers.  It's all dynamic, so no static pages.

Haven't found an answer that could help thus far.

Answer (score 2):

Consider adding something like the [Google Plus One](http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/) button to your site. It's very easy to implement and you don't have to worry about any backend stuff as a result.

Or [search on google.](http://www.google.com/search?q=add+a+rating+system+to+your+website)

Comment: The end result is that the "This answer helped my question" will return more relevant answers based on the search.

Comment: @obsideus which is why I didn't *just* say to Google it. I gave my answer; then included a link to a Google search I had previously found helpful. :)